# How to resolve "package file parameter missing" while uploading a package in AEM6.3?

Tags: aem

I am using AEM 6.3 on a linux machine. While uploading a package I am getting "`package file parameter missing`" error.

I have a "tmp" folder created and mentioned it in the start.bat file as below-

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir='/mnt/crx/author/tmp'
```

But nothing is being written in the "tmp" folder while uploading the package.

Do I need to mention it somewhere else also?

**tmp** folder has all the permissions..

Any leads?

Comment: The popup has normally an associated error message in the logs. Can you check for something like `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory` in your logs? 

If that's the case, it will be a permission issue. If not then try getting an error log dump for this error and we can look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a space issue. Though I have provided "`/mnt/crx/author/tmp`" path for the **tmp** folder, but it was using the server's default **tmp** directory for putting the temporary file during package installation. And that default tmp directory didn't have enough space and that's why this error pop up was coming..